# Axis labels also scroll along with the graph : how to disable?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-plot

First of all, thanks to the Core Plot team for the wonderful work on the graph APIs! Awesome! :)
The graph am drawing with Core Plot is coming out well. The issue arises when I scroll horizontally & the y-axes labels also scroll left along with the graph, as seen in the screenshots below:

The first screenshot is the initial view when the graph gets displayed.

[image]

As you can see in the 2nd screenshot below, the y-axes labels also have scrolled left, as I scroll the graph.

[image]

How to prevent the y-axes labels from scrolling, even though I should be able to scroll the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a constraint on the y-axis, e.g.,

```
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```